# How to retain google+ share count after server migration?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have made a url change with my site. After that it affects all my g+ share counts for specific page - it resets to 0. I want to migrate all the original share counts from old url to new url. I did set the g+ share button's data-href pointing to old url like what said from other researches that i saw, but still it doesn't reflect the original count. Can anyone help me regarding this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.